# Odd glitching when simply rotating

Tags: 3d-view

Probably best described by watching this quick clip:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S0hC9Vj-VZNjMcnOC_erDCnr--o1cug1/view?usp=sharing

Basically; simply rotating around the viewport glitches the zoom level. Probably a simple fix, but I've tried adjusting the orbit / pan settings and doesn't seem to change anything.

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file so that we can test? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Hi @moonboots - it's happening sporadicly with multiple files but here's the demo one:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QnkMLZvxLRzNV6AqkzwCoB9Rcv5jllfJ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: weird, it doesn't happen for me, I hope someone will answer

Comment: Thanks for trying @moonboots - it's not happening all the time, generally when there's a more complicated scene...   happens identically on 2 separate Macs with different versions of Blender installed